# Maximum Subarray sum and those index-Divide and Conquer

Tags: c++, divide-and-conquer

My code above about find maximum subarray sum and finding start index,end index of that subarray.

```
int Max(int a,int b){return (a>b)?a:b;}
int Max(int a,int b,int c){return Max(Max(a,b),c);}
int MaxAcrossSubArray(int arr[],int l,int m,int r,int &Start,int &End) 
{
    Start=m;//initialize start index
    int sum=arr[m];
    int sum_l=arr[m];
    for(int i=m-1;i>=l;--i)//include mid(---------|)
    {
        sum+=arr[i];
        if(sum>sum_l)
        {
            Start=i;
            sum_l=sum;
        }

    }
    End=m+1;//initialize end index
    sum=arr[m+1];
    int sum_r=arr[m+1];
    for(int i=m+2;i<=r;++i)//include mid(|-----------------)
    {
        sum+=arr[i];
        if(sum>sum_r){
            End=i;
            sum_r=sum;
        }
    }
    return sum_l+sum_r;//(-----------|---------------------)

}
int MaxSubArray(int arr[],int l,int r,int &Start,int &End)
{
    if(l==r)
    {
        Start=l;
        End=r;
        return arr[l];
    }

    else
    {
        int mid=(l+r)/2;
        int a=MaxSubArray(arr,l,mid,Start,End);
        int b=MaxSubArray(arr,mid+1,r,Start,End);
        int c=MaxAcrossSubArray(arr,l,mid,r,Start,End);
        int Maximum=Max(a,b,c);

        if(Maximum==a)
            return MaxSubArray(arr,l,mid,Start,End);
        else if(Maximum==b)
            return MaxSubArray(arr,mid+1,r,Start,End);
        else
            return MaxAcrossSubArray(arr,l,mid,r,Start,End);
    }

}
```

My algorithm run good for any case but i still need you guys help me to improve my algorithm for better.Is there any way to make it better?

Comment: Please define *better*. If you code works and you wonder whether it can be improved, it belongs to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow.

Comment: At very least, buffer the results of first recursive calls, then you don't need to do the same job twice (`a = maxSub(startA, endA); if(max == a) { start = startA; end = endA; return a; }`

Comment: Another thing for improvement would be to use standard library more extensively. For instance, there is no need for you to define int Max(int, int), since there is std::max for you already defined in header <algorithm>: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max . Then, naming could be better. 'arr', 'l', 'mid', 'r' do not sound very clear from code review point of view. And finally, as it was mentioned by @Fureeish , this should belong to CodeReview, not StackOverflow if there is no problem with your code.